# Possible to transfer session between 2 apache php instances

Tags: php, session

I have two identical VMs, containing Ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4, and PHP 7.0.4 running on different IPs.

In both the VMs I have a script doing some simple session procedures.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}
echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

The first VM gets accessed by a single client every minute and the corresponding counter gets increased. The other is not. I would like to somehow synchronize the state of the two machines.

When I transfer the files generated from /var/lib/php/sessions to the other machine I noticed that the counter starts from zero again.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible with just transferring files from the two machines? Is session information saved also in files other than the ones contained in /var/lib/php/sessions?

Comment: Imo, you have a synchronization issue. You think - sessions. I know sessions are unique to a cookie that is not shared. So, leave those alone So, how can I have different processes talk to each other? 1) A database table. Absolutely reliable and safe. put the information to share in the table from one process. The other process loads it and does what it wants. 100% reliable and safe and flexible. so, you fight with sessions and cookies? Why? I have no idea.

Comment: @RyanVincent how about a socket connection between the two servers to transfer data?

Comment: @RyanVincent My goal is to be able to completely migrate the apache running in VM1 to VM2. I am able to transfer the filesystem and the memory (using the CRIU tool). However, I find that when I want to have my session persist I need to transfer the cookies/session cookies. So I do, but for some reason it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with this is PHP/HTML it's stateless, the $_SESSION value for one client will be different for another.  The only way to make this work is to save the $_SESSION value to something stateful like a database or file.  Then, add a simple REST interface to the first machine that allows the second one to retrieve the file contents.  The code below is untested, but presents the general idea.

```
    //Machine 1
    <?php
    $secret_key = 'secret123'; //Same on both machines, make this a long string of random charecters

    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['count']++;
    }

    //Write the count value to a file
    $countFile = fopen('count.txt','w');
    fwrite($countFile,$_SESSION['count']);
    fclose($countFile);



    //Handle requests from machine 2
    if(isset($_GET['request_count'])) {
        if($_GET['request_count'] == $secret_key) {
            echo file_get_contents('count.txt');
            exit;
        }
    }

    echo $_SESSION['count'];
    ?>

    //Machine 2
    <?php
    $secret_key = 'secret123';
    $machine_1_URL = 'localhost';

    //Init curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $machine1URL . "/?request_count=" . $secret_key
    ));

    //Get the data from machine 1
    echo curl_exec($ch);

    //Alternatively you can set the value like this:
    $_SESSION['count'] = intval(curl_exec($ch));
    ?>
```

I wouldn't get in the business of transferring session files between machines when you can use well tested, known methods instead of something that might be broken by a PHP update.